# Inheritance and Overriding typed properties

Tags: php, inheritance

I am trying to make wild things with inheritance in PHP. I e.g. the following code, which doesn't work

```
class Animal {
    public Food $food;
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    public Fish $food; //so this part doesn't work, eventhough Fish extends from Food
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    public Meat $food; //so this part doesn't work, eventhough Meat extends from Food
}

class Food {
    public int $weightInKilograms;
}

class Fish extends Food {
    public bool $isSaltWaterFish;
}
class Meat extends Food {
    public bool $isRawMeat;
}
```

So how can i make the part work, where i put my comment in the code above? I don't understand why this shouldn't work since ChildX IS also the same like SuperX if it extends SuperX.

I get the following error:

> **Fatal error**:  Type of Cat::$food must be Food (as in
> class Animal) in **[...][...]** on line **6**

Comment: Side note: this question relates to PHP in general, so you might want to remove the framework tags, as it's not specifically tied to any of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Quick answer

This is not possible.

### Short answer

In super class `Animal` add an abstract method with a `Food` parameter as

Animal.php

```
abstract public function setFood(Food $food);
```

Cat.php

```
public function setFood(Food $food) {
   if (!$food instanceof Fish) {
      throw new InvalidArgumentException(self::class . " only support " . Fish::class . " objects.");
   }
   $this->food = $food;
}
```